# Is there a way with which we can get hands on 'compiled code' of dependencies when using Ant Build?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant

I am working on a project on which somebody earlier worked, the project is built using Ant in Intellij. I want to see the code of the dependent package but all I see is /* compiled code */. Is there a way around it?

[image to the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpk5p.png)

Comment: Intellij should have a built in decompiler. Are you using community edition?

Comment: highlight the variable/type you want to view and press ctrl+b to inspect the source code.

Comment: @HenryLin I am using Mac, so I suppose you are suggesting command+b?, does it work for methods as well?

Comment: @BoristheSpider Yes I am using community edition, how can I use decompiler?

Comment: @simar15 cmd+b is the mac equivalent to ctrl+b in windows. And yup, it works on everything, provided the code compiles properly and consequently can be indexed.

Comment: @HenryLin no tried using, cmd+b, nothing changed still getting 'compiled code'

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thanks the plugin for decompiler worked!